# Trying to create an ArrayList<Integer> with a Set of ints

Tags: java, arraylist, hashmap, set

I started with a `HashMap<String, int>`

In the first line of this sample code I created an `ArrayList<String>` with the keySet of the Hashmap. Then I attempted to create an `ArrayList<Integer>` with the entrySet of the same HashMap. Both of these assignments use the same syntax and process but the integer hashmap is giving the error message. It sounds like the problem comes from the fact that I am trying to use a Set containing int's to populate an Integer ArrayList. I know int is a primitive and Integer is an object but I'm not sure what I need to change in the code.

```
    ArrayList<String> keys = new ArrayList<String>(ngram.keySet());
    ArrayList<Integer> values = new ArrayList<Integer>(ngram.entrySet());
```

Comment: `entrySet` doesn't give you the values, it gives you the map entries.  `values()` gives you the values.

Comment: entrySet returns set of Entry class - not Integer

Comment: @azurefrog thanks man, that's exactly what I needed to know. It wasn't clear on the site that I was on and Java doesn't lend itself to quick and easy testing :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling [the `entrySet()` method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#entrySet--), which will give you a `Set<Entry<String, Integer>>`, not a `Set<Integer>`.

If you want the values, call [the `values()` method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#values--), which will return a `Collection<Integer>`.